# Auto Update Cordova AngularJS Updates onto Tethered Android Device via Visual Studio

Tags: android, angularjs, visual-studio, cordova

I am writing a phone app using Cordova and AngularJS via Visual Studio 2013. I am at a point where I am debugging my app via a tethered android phone.  I can easily manipulate the DOM realtime via Visual Studio and it auto updates the DOM on the phone, but does anybody know if it is possible to edit the JS in VS and have it auto-update onto the tethered device rather than having to re-build / re-deploy?

Comment: Would be lovely, but I'd imagine it would have to reboot the app every time even if you could do this just to prevent inconsistent states in the app. But this certainly would save time in the dev/deploy loop.